# Get MimeType from file name in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mime-types

I can't find any MS documentation on how to get the MimeType from a file name in WinPhone 8. Most of the references say to use System.Web.MimeMapping. But that library is not compatible with WinPhone 8. Anything else I can try or look at? Every other link online has to do with IIS and how to configure that.